# Angular - How to set Angular Material datepicker Birth Date to max of 18 years

Tags: angular, angular-material

In Angular-12, I am using Material datepicker for date of birth:

Component:

```
tomorrow = new Date();
constructor(
  private router: Router,
) {
  this.tomorrow.setDate(this.tomorrow.getDate());
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
  <label for="dob">Date of Birth:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="form-group">

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%" fxFlex.gt-sm>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dob" placeholder="Choose a date" [max]="tomorrow" formControlName="dob" readonly required>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dob"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #dob></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="fp.dob.touched && fp.dob.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="fp.dob.hasError('required')">
      <div class="text-danger">
        Date of Birth is required!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the min date to 18 years so that any candidate below 18 years will not be able to register.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit it to 18 year olds. You actually want to set the *max* to todays date minus 18 years, not the min.

In your component constructor something like this(although I would recommend you use ngOnInit instead for components).

```
maxDob: Date;
constructor(
  private router: Router,
) {
  const today = new Date();
  this.maxDob = new Date(
    today.getFullYear() - 18,
    today.getMonth(),
    today.getDate()
  );
}
```

And make sure to change your html as well

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dob" placeholder="Choose a date" [max]="maxDob" formControlName="dob" readonly required>
```

Here's a stackblitz example with ngOnInit

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-4erepd?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[max]` to compute maximum value for the date picker.

Component

```
 export class DatepickerMinMaxExample implements OnInit {
  maxDate: Date;
  date: Date;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate.setMonth(this.maxDate.getMonth() - 12 * 18);
  }
}
```

Template

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput #input="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="date" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="input.hasError('matDatepickerMax')">Date should be inferior</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is a [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffjzt8-gqbtxb?file=app/datepicker-min-max-example.html)